# Compare the contents of dynamically generated archives

Tags: backup, tar

Short question: I have two dynamically generated tar archives (so they have different timestamps), how can I compare them, ignoring any different in time?

Backgrounds...

I am doing some backup, in which I use a script to generate things that needs to be backed up, put them in to a directory, then tar the directory and keep several old versions. The backup script needs to run every 30 minutes to make sure we don't lose hours of work.

Now I realize that there are periods of time that the data doesn't change, so it doesn't make sense to store duplicates of the same thing over and over again. I would like to compare the archives before saving. My attempt was to run `cmp newdata.tar.gz olddata.tar.gz` and only store `newdata.tar.gz` if it contains new data. Apparently that didn't work, because there are different timestamps.

Comment: I'm suspecting timestamps because everything else is the same. Even diff reports nothing else but time changes.

Answer (score 2):

Here are three approaches. The first has my preference.

#### Change the file generation process

Instead of regenerating the files indiscriminately (`dump_table foo >foo.dump`), keep the old file if it's identical to the new one.

```
dump_table foo >foo.dump.new
if cmp foo.dump foo.dump.new; then
  rm foo.dump.new
else
  mv foo.dump.new foo.dump
fi
```

#### Mount the archives as directories

Use [AVFS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/avf/) to create a view of your entire directory hierarchy where all archives have an associated directory (same name with `#` tacked on at the end) that appears to hold the archive content.

```
mountavfs
d=$(date -d %Y%m%d%H%M%S); mkdir $d; tar czf /path/to/$d.tgz $d; rmdir $d
cd /path/to/back/up
rsync -ac --compare-dest=~/.avfs/path/to/yesterday.tgz . ~/.avfs/path/to/$d.tgz
```

#### Use a backup tool with the requisite feature

Backup programs need to be extremely reliable. It's hard for a home-grown solution to cover all cases. So consider a full-blown backup program. I think [duplicity](http://www.nongnu.org/duplicity/) would do what you require: it performs incremental backups, and it uses the rsync algorithm, so it shouldn't waste any space on data that's already there.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a backup tool like `backup2l`, that can be configured to any level of differential backups and any number of full backups. `backup2l` is ran as a cronjob in any frequency you like and it is configured by setting some values to its conf file. It is actually a wrapper for tar or afio, it keeps file listings with hashes for finding changes and provides an easy way to get status or restore a file by date.

A second option is to use a version control system such as `cvs`, `svn`, `git` etc. Setup a cronjob that will make automatic commits (and maybe daily tagging). Based on the vcs choice, you may need some scripting to add new files or remove old ones.

For a frequency of every half hour, I'd recommend the vcs option. But you can combine the two by using `backup2l` (or any other backup tool) to also backup the vcs repository (redundancy of backups is always good).

Answer (score 0):

Do the files inside the archives change, or are just new ones added?

If you only add files, and don't change any, try something like this:

```
tar ztf olddata.tar.gz | sort > tmpfile1
tar ztf newdata.tar.gz | sort > tmpfile2
diff tmpfile{1,2} > /dev/null
if test $? -eq 0
then
  echo ignore newdata.tar.gz
else
  echo keep olddata.tar.gz
fi
rm tmpfile{1,2}
```

Note the absence of `v` from the tar table of contents commands.

If you just want to skip archives with identical contents, add a `v` to the mix, as in:

```
tar ztvf olddata.tar.gz | sort > tmpfile1
```

and so on.

Comment: Actually, the files inside the archives were generated through several ways, including querying the database...

Comment: @phunehehe: see my last edit, and give it a try. Just compare the (sorted) table of contents from the archives you want to compare. Omit the `> /dev/null` to see what has changed between revisions.

Comment: No I don't want to skip files just because of the name, I want to check the contents as well.

Comment: @phunehehe: the `mtime` of files change when they are updated, the diff of the sorted output of `tar ztvf` will get them. **Try it**

Comment: @Matt the files are not updated, they are newly created every time. I have code to query the database and put the result into text.

Comment: @phunehehe: then `tar` is not the proper tool to do incremental backups. You could probably keep a "staging area" for the previous backups contents, and diff each file before overwriting, and then archive the staging area if at least 1 file has changed since the last time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, then:

```
OLDSUM=`tar zxOf olddata.tar.gz | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'`
NEWSUM=`tar zxOf newdata.tar.gz | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'`
if test "${NEWSUM}" != "${OLDSUM}"
then
  echo save newdata.tar.gz
else
  echo nothing changed
fi
```

The capital `O` extracts the archive contents to `stdout`.

It will not work, however, unless the files are added to the archive in the exact same order (which they probably are, though).